# Adding text to images while using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The image shows you what I'm attempting to do. I've tried various methods but I don't seem to be getting any luck. i'm also trying to make it responsive, however when I make the screen smaller the boxes start overlapping each other.
         https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjIh2.jpg

The other method I used was to make each of the boxes an image and add text but I had came across a similar problem when the screen was resized.
        https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFYiJ.jpg

```
<div class="container-bg">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="products">
            <h1>PRODUCTS</h1>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                  <img src="img/red.png" class="img-responsive">
                  <p class="bottom">PPE</p>
                </div>
              </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                  <img src="img/green.png" class="img-responsive">
                  <p class="bottom">FOOTWEAR</p>
                </div>
              </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                  <img src="img/blue.png" class="img-responsive">
                  <p class="bottom">CLOTHING</p>
                </div>
              </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                  <img src="img/black.png" class="img-responsive">
                  <p class="bottom">RAIL TOOLS</p>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>


    .box{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: ;
    display: inline-grid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    }

    .box img{
     width: 250px;
    height:200px;
    }

    .bottom,
    .right{
     margin:5em;
     position:absolute;
      }

      .bottom{
        bottom: 0px;
        }

      .right{
       right: 0px;
       top: 0px;
       }
```

Comment: Hi @Will, I know it seems obvious, but could you try explain exactly what you're trying to do here? What would you like it to look like? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Hi @Tom, sorry if I didn't explain it clear enough. the first image/link (https://imgur.com/ALX9qTD ) shows you what I want the end product to look like. I've tried to do this by making 4 (col-md-3) columns separate colours and adding text. the second way was to add for different images and added text to them. The problem is not getting them to display on  the screen but more to function smoothly. https://imgur.com/Ma3V27B

Comment: What I'm not clear on is whether you want the black "Shop Now" text area, or the text at the top of each image (ie. 'Rail Tools) or both.  Your HTML doesn't really line up with the image you use as your final output goal.

Comment: @Tom here is a example of what I'm trying to achieve, just look below were it says Estate Pro services (http://preview.themeforest.net/item/estate-pro-real-estate-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/12589690?_ga=2.4809782.484347529.1526471472-1962077792.1526471472)

Comment: Don't use images, they can't be searched/copied/edited easily. You want to make the job of would-be helpers as easy as possible!

Comment: @RobertC I want the (e.g. rail tools) on top using html but If I could add the "shop now" aswell the would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your use of the `img-responsive` class I'm making an assumption that you're utilizing Bootstrap 3.x, though this solution would work for 4.x with minimum alterations (mostly changing `imp-responsive` to `img-fluid` and dropping the `xs` suffix).

You're on the right track with relying on `position:absolute`.  It's the only way to position your text above the `<img>` without swapping your image out for a `background`.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
  
.box p,
.box h2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.box h2 {
  padding: 2vmax;
  font-size: 2vmax;
}

.box p {
  bottom: 0;
  background: RGBA(0,0,0,0.85);
  padding: .5vmax 1vmax;
  font-size: 1vmax;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <div class="box">
        <h2>Name One</h2>
        <p>Test One</p>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/450/fc4349/ff8084/&text=Image" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <div class="box">
        <h2>Name One</h2>
        <p>Test Two</p>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/450/8dc041/a6d85b/&text=Image" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <div class="box">
        <h2>Name One</h2>
        <p>Test Three</p>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/450/3598d8/5fb3ea/&text=Image" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <div class="box">
        <h2>Name One</h2>
        <p>Test Four</p>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/450/292c33/4a4f5b/&text=Image" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Note: You can see this same code on Bootply (where it will appear larger by default): https://www.bootply.com/49AuIAv7Bn

Mainly what you need to account for here is the responsive behavior.  For my example I relied on a quick and dirty `vmax` unit, though you would have greater control / consistency utilizing `@media` breakpoints to change the font and padding units.

If you were to explore that route I would strongly recommend simply employing the media breakpoints used by Bootstrap 3.x: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries